# Using R to find probability

Tags: r, combinations, probability

a) In a group of 20 people there are three sisters. The group is separated at
random into two groups of 10. What is the probability that the sisters are in the
same group?
b) Write R-code to solve problem using simulation.

I have difficulty in part B. I can't understand how i can simulate this situation

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a bit of a homework dump - it would be preferable to see a bit of effort on your part, but it seems you don't know where to start.

I have annotated the following code to show one possible approach

```r
# Make the sample reproducible
set.seed(69)

# Calculate the probability that the brothers will be in the same group
prob_calculated <- 20/20 * 9/19 * 8/18

# Create our sample space. Here, 1 stands for one of the brothers, 
# a zero means a non-brother:
space <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

# Create an empty vector to store the results of our simulation
vec <- logical()

# For 10,000 simulations, we will draw 10 numbers from space without replacement.
# If the sum of the sample is three or zero, the brothers are all in the same group.
# We store the result of each simulation in the vector vec at position i.
for(i in 1:10000) {
  samp <- sample(space, 10)
  vec[i] <- sum(samp) == 0 | sum(samp) == 3
}

# The proportion of TRUE results in vec estmates the probability
prob_simulated <- length(which(vec))/10000

# Now we present the results for comparison
c(prob_calculated = prob_calculated, prob_simulated = prob_simulated)
#> prob_calculated  prob_simulated 
#>       0.2105263       0.2149000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>